# How to find a Solution of this $(3x + y - z)p + (x + y - z)q = 2(z -y)$ linear PDE of first order?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

The given equation is $$(3x + y - z)p + (x + y - z)q = 2(z -y)$$ where $$p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$ In my textbook we were prescribed a certain method to solve such equations : applying
 $ \frac{dx}{P} = \frac{dy}{Q} = \frac{dz}{R}$ where $P = (3x + y - z), Q = (x + y - z), R = 2(z -y)$ but it seems I could not manipulate the above method appropriately.

Generally the solution must come out in the format : $F(u,v) = 0$ where $u$ and $v$ are some functions of $x, y, z$ if we apply this method.My problem is i am not getting the required $u, v$, which matches the book answers.

Note that $x, y$ are independent variables, and $z$ is a dependent variable of $x,y$, and $u,v$ are supposedly expected answers which are themselves functions of $x, y, z$, and so here i need to find the functions $u,v$. Also note that here $p$ is different from $P$ same goes about $q$ and $Q$.

Comment: Is there not a confusion in the wording of your question ?  The method using  $ \frac{dx}{P} = \frac{dy}{Q} = \frac{dz}{R}$ where $P = (3x + y - z), Q = (x + y - z), R = 2(z -y)$ is valid if $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ but not in the case $q = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ as you wrote.

Comment: Also, the wording is ambiguous about what are the variables and what are the function(s). Can you state clearly : $x$ is either a variable, or function of what variable(s) ? $y$ is either a variable, or a function of what variable(s) ? $z$ is either a variable, or a function of what variable(s) ?

Comment: @JJacquelin do re-edit it, if you find my words confusing, am a bit naive to English.

Comment: @JJacquelin, ok lemme re-edit about functions and independent variables

Comment: In your question, you wrote $q = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$. This is a non-sens since $y$ isn't a function, but is a variable independent of $x$.

Comment: @JJacquelin thanks, for pointing out, it seems i had made a lot of mistakes...

Comment: Now, all is OK. The method proposed in your book can be applied. It is called "Method of characteristics". What exactly is your problem to apply this method ?

Comment: @JJacquelin, the $u, v$ i get do not match the given answers...

Comment: To get $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$ you have to solve the system of differential equations $\frac{dx}{3x+y-z}=\frac{dy}{x+y-z}=\frac{dz}{2(z-y)}$

Comment: @JJacquelin, i did attempt exactly that way, but to no avail

Comment: If what you get doesn't match the given answer, I cannot help you without seeing all the steps of your calculus. I suggest you to type it in addition to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45861/discussion-between-arnav-das-and-jjacquelin).

Comment: @JJacquelin, well can you solve that independently, i mean like all by yourself, because i have pretty much a strong guess that whatever i did after that step are pretty much wrong.....or should i add in the question the book given answers that is values of $u,v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of solving thanks to the method of characteristics :

[image]

Don't forget that an implicite equation can be written on an infinity of different forms, but all equivalent, that is giving the same general solution, even if the implicite equations look different. So, if your book gives an apparently different equation, the equation found above can be transformed to appear exactly like the equation in the book.

Comment: A very much thank you for your painstaking efforts, and no my book answers actually match